# How to launch MongoDB local server on a new command line

Tags: node.js

I am trying to launch MongoDB local server at the beginning of my program so I don't have to open it manually every time.

I tried to use the `execFile` from `child_process`. It works but runs the server on the current cmd and doesn't let the rest of the program run.
I also tried using `async/await` but doesn't seem to change anything.

### launchLocalServer.js:

```
const exec = require("child_process").execFile;

exec("C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin/mongod.exe", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

When I run: 
`"dev": "node config/launchLocalServer.js && concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""`

```
C:\Users\Bera\workspace\lang-talk>npm run dev

> lang-talk@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Bera\workspace\lang-talk
> node config/launchLocalServer.js && concurrently "npm run server" "npm 
run client"
```

And the program doesn't progress.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem 5 secs after posting the question. I just moved `node config/launchLocalServer.js` inside `concurrently`.
Like so:
    `concurrently \"node config/launchLocalServer.js\" \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"`

Comment: You might want to consider starting the MongoDB server with your npm script instead of executing it from JS. That's what npm scripts are for.